# Call function from another file - Discord bot

Tags: python, api, async-await, discord, discord.py

I am not familiar with Discord bots or much of Python so here's a simple question I can't figure out the answer to.

I have two files; discord_bot.py and test.py
How do I forward a message from test.py to send it to a channel in Discord?

**test.py**

```
import discord_bot

discord_bot.signal(msg = "Hi")
```

**discord_bot.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '1234567890'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def signal(ctx, *, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

The Discord bot works fine but calling the signal function from test is not the correct way to do it. Any help here please?

Comment: What channel are you trying to send this message to? Sorry if it's not much help, but I would suggest using the discord methods to find the channel you want to send this message to, since it's not explicit when you are running discord_bot.signal from test.py.

Comment: If I don't speify a channel, it sends it to the default channel - general

Comment: I think the steps you might need to take would be to firstly get the list of all channels your bot can see, then find the one named "general" and send the message to it. So it would be something like: [a for a in bot.get_channels() if a.name == 'general'][0].send(msg)  (I haven't tested this line of code so please don't use it)

Comment: Although that would not work if your bot can see multiple "general" channels.

Comment: Okay I guess I forgot to mention this, when I call the signal() function from the test.py file, it does not enter the signal() in the discord_bot.py at all (tried with prints). And there is only one channel at the moment.

Comment: Oh, I see. I noticed that your ctx and msg arguments in your signal function are positional, which means they are required in every call. Maybe try writing ctx=None and msg=None to make sure they aren't required, then in your signal function perform something on ctx and msg when they are None to make sure they don't cause any errors. Then, your signal function should at least be called successfully.

Comment: Nope that still doesn't work sadly. I think there is a specific way to call the signal function and what I did isn't correct.

Comment: Ah I don't know why I didn't realise. Your function is a coroutine, it needs to be `await`ed. Sorry, I'm half asleep. To `await` a coroutine, you would need to add the `await` keyword before your function call, but you can only do that from within a coroutine, which makes this a bit difficult...

Answer (score 5):

This is a lot to unpack.

**0. Never post your discord token online.** Discord may automatically invalidate your token if it's posted online.

**1. You are not running your bot at the moment, add `bot.run(TOKEN)` at the end**

**2. How the commands of the discord bot extension work**

`@bot.command()` is a [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), if you do not know how they work, read up on it. Overly simplified, they take your function and **register** in the bot.

The inner workings of the `commands` extension are basically:

1. Register all commands by loading the decorators
2. Whenever a message arrives, check if it contains a prefix and if so, check if it fits a command.
3. If both checks from 2 passed, construct a [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object, then pass that object to the function. Something like the following:

```py
signal(ctx, *args)
```

This is why the ctx object can't be positional, because the way the function is called in the inner workings of the bot as a normal argument.

**4. Do not try to mess with creating your own context object, unless you know what you're doing.** You only need to create context objects if you're overriding the default message parser.

**5. Don't use commands for this.**

What you want to do, as far as I can tell:
Call a command yourself. This is easy enough:

file 1:

```py
@bot.command()
async def signal(ctx, *, msg):
    print(msg)
```

file 2:

```py
from file1 import signal
import asyncio # if you don't know asyncio, read up on it

asyncio.run(signal(None, 'This is an argument'))
```

This works easily, it prints your stuff. But you don't want it to be printed, right? You want it to be **sent** in a **channel**. This is what you need the context object for, which I said before, to not construct yourself. So how do we actually do this?

The answer is: **Don't use commands**. They are used for *reacting* to messages, not to be called by themselves.

**6. The solution you (probably) want**

So the major changes here are:

1. signal is now a normal async function with no decorator
2. We actually specify a channel where we want the stuff to be sent in as an argument of the function

file 1:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'do not share your token online'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# as the channel_id, pass the channel_id you want the message to be sent in
async def signal(msg, channel_id):
    global bot # getting our bot variable from the global context
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Major changes here are:

1. We use asyncio.run to call the function. Async functions cannot be called with regular syntax.
2. You'll probably need to run file2.py to start the program. Running file1 will not load file2.

file 2

```
from file1 import signal
from time import sleep
import asyncio

sleep(5) # We need to give our bot time to log in, or it won't work
asyncio.run(signal('hi!', 123))
```

Comment: I tried your answer but when i run file 2 in the file1 import the bot keeps "on line" so nothing happens, i'm a newbie on async functions so i dont know if this is the expected behavior or im doing something wrong

Comment: @Jaziel_Inc please open a new question for this particular problem